# Mongo index for nested map in collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing, collections, nested

I need to create mongo index on collection, which includes nested map. 
The structure looks like that

```
"settings1" : {
        "settings2" : {
            "1" : {
                "b1" : false,
                "b2" : false,
                "b3" : false,
                "b4" : false,
                "b5" : false
            },
            "2" : {
                "b1" : true,
                "b2" : false,
                "b3" : false,
                "b4" : false,
                "b5" : false
            }
         }
}
```

I need to create index on nested ids, so "1", "2" etc. (Java impl for settings2 is map, which keys are ids, values are the objects with bool values).

***How can I create the index without changing the structure of the collection?***

The idea which I have is like

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({
    "settings1.settings2": 1
}, {
    name: "indexName",
    background: true
});
```

But I think, it is not ok at all... Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you saying it is not ok? can you please explain?

Comment: You don't index keys, but their values. So, if you have the idea that the index shall help you find the key existance (like "1", "2", etc.) you're out of luck. You might add an array containig the existing keys and index that. If you want to index by values, you'll have to insert multiple indexes for "settings1.settings2.1", "settings1.settings2.2", and so on.

Comment: @notionquest I implemented that kind of approach only for values. I mean only when structure would be without boolean values.

Comment: @mtj what do you mean by "You might add an array containig the existing keys and index that". Add array where?

Comment: @Dominika Add something like "settings1.settings2.containedKeys":["1", "2"] to the document and create an index on this field ("settings1.settings2.containedKeys") - that might help you to check the existance of the keys themselves, if that is the critical path concerning performance.